# MySQL: Select minimum values of dataset without using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the minimum values! (plural) from a table without using a subquery? The table contains following data (sorry four the mouse):

[image: Three possible tables]

As you can see, I always want to select the minimum values. If there are the same values (table 2 & 3) the query shall give all rows, because there is no minimum. I'm using MySQL. I don't want to use a subquery if possible because of performance reasons. A min(value) and group by id doesn't work either, because of the unique ids.

Thanks in advance
ninsky

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this cannot be done without a subquery in MySQL.  For example:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   value =
        (
        select  min(value)
        from    YourTable
        )
```

Comment: As an extension to this comment, assuming you have an index on this column, you should never have any slow downs for this query.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not trust MySQL in performance you can split query proposed by Andomar to 2 atomic subquery